# Add Input Field in Simple Model Contact Form (smcf) plugin

Tags: posts, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using nice SMCF ([Contact Form](http://beurl.in/9)) want to add a wordpress post list Drop Down menu in 
 "Simple Model Contact form"

here what i added on line '195' to try look.

```
$output .= "<div class='colmsg'><label for='smcf-message'>*" . __("Message", "smcf") . ": </label>
        <select name="">
  <option>Post1</option>
  <option>Post2</option>
  <option>Post1</option></select></div><br/>";
```

after saving / uploading file, it showing

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in plugins/simplemodal-contact-form-smcf/smcf.php on line 201
```

please help me how to get post list in form. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just wasn't concatenated correctly (i.e. misuse of single/double quotes). This'll work:

```
$output .= '<div class="colmsg"><label for="smcf-message">*' . __("Message", "smcf") . ': </label>
        <select name="">
  <option>Post1</option>
  <option>Post2</option>
  <option>Post1</option></select></div><br/>';
```

Comment: thank you so much for this.
 can you help me ? i want all posts list in this drop down menu.

Comment: thanks !! please have a look this screenshot what i want to do ... http://beurl.in/m

Comment: i have added this code for post list <select class="post_list_smcf" name="">

  <option>'.wp_get_archives('').'</option></select> but it display blank with no posts

Comment: Open a new question and we can help you there.

Comment: posted here is http://beurl.in/e